# ibm.data.informix is not getting the correct data out of the database

Tags: .net, database, informix

Server: IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 11.70.FC1GE 
Client: IBM Data Server Driver package 5765-F41
Dotnet Client DLL:

IBM.Data.Informix.dll
       File version: 9.7.4.2 
       Assembly Version: 9.0.0.2
       Product Version: 9.7.4.2

Table info:

```
Column name     Type                       Nulls

timeid          interval day to minute     yes
cb1             smallint                   yes
cb2             smallint                   yes
data1           smallfloat                 yes
data2           smallfloat                 yes
...
data60          smallfloat                 yes
data61          smallfloat                 yes
```

.Net Code:

```
dim _conn as New IfxConnection("Database=HMS;Server=10.1.1.9:17859;UID=informix;Password=informix;")
_conn.Open()

Dim _cmdstr As String = "select * from data"
Dim _cmd As New IfxCommand(_cmdstr, _connection)
Dim _dr As IfxDataReader = _cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SingleResult)
While _dr.Read
Debug.WriteLine(_dr.GetValue(0))
next
```

The type of _dr.GetValue(0) is a string.
As you can see under here a lot of the interval data is not fetched correctly! (Only the first 3 chars)

This would cause a big loss of data.
Is there anybody who knows how I can solve this??

Thx in advance.

```
Output from debug writeline: (... = good data I left out)

1 00:00
...
2 00:45
2 01:00
2 0
2 01:30
2 01:45
...
2 23:30
2 23:45
3 0
3 00:15
3 00:30
...
3 02:00
3 02:15
3 0
3 02:45
3 03:00
...
4 03:30
4 03:45
4 0
4 04:15
4 04:30
...
5 02:15
5 02:30
5 0
5 03:00
5 03:15
...
5 04:45
5 05:00
5 0
5 05:30
5 05:45
...
6 06:00
6 06:15
6 0
6 0
6 07:00
6 07:15
...
7 05:00
7 05:15
7 0
7 05:45
7 06:00
...
7 07:30
7 07:45
7 0
7 08:15
7 08:30
...
8 08:45
8 09:00
8 0
8 0
8 09:45
8 10:00
...
9 07:45
9 08:00
9 0
9 08:30
9 08:45
...
9 10:15
9 10:30
9 1
9 11:00
9 11:15
...
10 11:30
10 11:45
10 1
10 12:15
10 12:30
...
11 10:15
11 10:30
11 1
11 11:00
11 11:15
...
11 12:45
11 13:00
11 1
11 13:30
11 13:45
...
12 14:00
12 14:15
12 1
12 1
12 15:00
12 15:15
...
13 12:45
13 13:00
13 1
13 1
13 13:45
13 14:00
...
13 15:30
13 15:45
13 1
13 16:15
13 16:30
...
14 16:45
14 17:00
14 1
14 17:30
14 17:45
...
15 15:30
15 15:45
15 1
15 16:15
15 16:30
...
15 18:00
15 18:15
15 1
15 18:45
15 19:00
...
16 19:15
16 19:30
16 1
16 20:00
16 20:15
...
17 18:00
17 18:15
17 1
17 18:45
17 19:00
...
17 20:30
17 20:45
17 2
17 21:15
17 21:30
...
18 21:45
18 22:00
18 2
18 22:30
18 22:45
...
19 20:30
19 20:45
19 2
19 21:15
19 21:30
...
19 23:00
19 23:15
19 2
19 2
20 00:00
20 00:15
...
21 00:15
21 00:30
21 0
21 0
21 01:15
21 01:30
...
21 23:15
21 23:30
21 2
22 00:00
22 00:15
..
22 01:45
22 02:00
22 0
22 02:30
22 02:45
...
23 03:00
23 03:15
23 0
23 03:45
23 04:00
...
24 01:45
24 02:00
24 0
24 02:30
24 02:45
...
24 04:15
24 04:30
24 0
24 05:00
24 05:15
...
25 05:30
25 05:45
25 0
25 06:15
25 06:30
...
26 06:45
26 07:00
26 0
26 07:30
26 07:45
...
27 08:00
27 08:15
27 0
27 08:45
27 09:00
...
29 10:30
29 10:45
29 1
29 1
29 11:30
29 11:45
...
30 12:00
30 12:15
30 1
30 12:45
30 13:00
...
30 23:45
```

Comment: Have you checked it with other technology like JDBC or ODBC? Can you give us shorter example of schema, query, required (correct) result (from JDBC/ODBC etc) and incorrect result (from .Net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through ODBC it worked correctly.

With another program that uses JDBC it worked correctly.

With an old C-program that uses embedded-sql it worked correctly.

While running a bit out of time I had a dirty fix by doing a cast to nvarchar(9)

so the SQL statement became:

```
select cast(timeid as nvarchar(9)), * from data
```